# 紙にソースコードを手書きすることについて

Tags: untagged

適切な質問かどうか怪しいのですが、投稿させていただきます。

先日、プログラマの採用試験で紙にソースコードをかかされるというものがありました。
かつてはコーディングシートというものがあり、手描きの習慣があったのは知っていますし、
試験で紙にかかされることもあるというのは噂では聞いておりました。

実際にやってみるととても難しく、関数の綴りが手書きだと出てこなかったり、カッコの数がわからなくなったり、
行数がどれくらいになるか想定できず、なんども書きなおしたりし、修正したいけど手書きだと手間がかかりすぎてあきらめたり、
結局のところ満足のいくコードは書けず、「こんな糞コード実装するとしたら犯罪だなー」という感じでした。

紙にもできるだけ上手にコードを書くにはどういう工夫をしたらよいのでしょうか。
コツなどはあるのでしょうか・・・。

また、そもそもこのテストに意味はあるのかという疑問もあります。
みなさんはどのように感じますか?

Comment: [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) でもしばしば話題になっているみたいですね．[1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109775) [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196987) [3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98905) などなど．

Answer (score 1):

僕はいつもの環境でないとプログラミングの力は測れないと思うので、あまり意味が無いかと思います。暗記していることが重要なのではなく、正しく使えるかどうかなので、スペル覚えていなくても補完で不自由なく正しいものが使えれば良いとも思います。

僕も何度か面接でコードを書く機会がありましたが、どれも緊張と「自分のPCでできたら…」って思ってしまって良い思い出がありません(笑)

Answer (score 0):

そのテストは理解度を測るのに一番確実なので意味があると思います。
(日本語下手ですいません)